# ArcGIS Combine Fuzzy Membership and Weighted Sum

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, overlay, analysis

I would like to combine the workflow of fuzzy membership and weighted overlay for a suitability analysis and would like to ask if this is "allowed" scientifically.

I have severeal criteria, some would first use Fuzzy Membership to get a membership value from 0-1, some other criteria do not use Fuzzy Membership before (they get a Value from 0-10 through another method).

Then I would standardize the fuzzy value...multiply it with 10, that all criteria have values from 0-10.

After that I wouldn't use "Fuzzy Overlay", but I would use "Weighted Sum" and weight all criteria.

Now my question is: Is this "allowed" to combine Fuzzy membership and Weighted Overlay, or do I have to use "fuzzy overlay" when I work with fuzzy memberships? I would use "Fuzzy Membership" just for the standardization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That I believe your approach is completely valid. You are using a function to assign suitability values, the fact that the function is implemented in `Fuzzy Membership` tool does not mean that you can not use it in another context.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are looking for some referenes then I can recommend two articles: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9671.2011.01260.x/abstract and http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02693799308901964. In both cases the authors did something very close to what you are suggesting.